# rails assign variable only when it's ajax request or vice versa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

i'm new to rails and I am trying to implement an endless page. 
For the controller index I have:

```
    def index
        @messages = @conversation.messages.order('created_at DESC')
                         .paginate(page: params[:page],
                                   per_page: 8)
        @match = @conversation.match
        @bid = @conversation.bid unless @conversation.bid.nil?
        @table = @match.table unless @match.nil?
        read_message
        get_participant
    end
```

then when I click the button 'load more messages', then it fires an ajax request to get the next page's messages. But this time I don't want the @bid, @table variable anymore. But each time it gets to my controller, it will hit again the database.

So my question is that is there a way to assign certain variable only when it's an ajax request? or vice versa?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the AJAX request, you can send a custom header with whatever value you want. So, send something like a `X-IS-AJAX-REQUEST` header with a value of `true`. With this, you can get the value of that header in Rails and use a conditional to set only the variables that need to be set. Something like this could work:

```
def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages.order('created_at DESC')
                     .paginate(page: params[:page],
                               per_page: 8)
    @match = @conversation.match
    unless request.headers['X-IS-AJAX-REQUEST'] then
       @bid = @conversation.bid unless @conversation.bid.nil?
       @table = @match.table unless @match.nil?
    end
    read_message
    get_participant
end
```

Comment: I ended up using if request.xhr?  the built-in short-cuts in rails